# Passing querystring from one page to another through javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, query-string

I have two different pages. I want to send querystring from one to another. below is my sample code that i have tried

```
window.location.search = 'id='+hidposid.value; 
window.location.href="editviewposition.aspx";
```

in another page i retrieve the value

```
cookie1 = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString("id") ' returns ""
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#btnQueryString").bind("click", function () {
            var url = "Page2.htm?name=" + encodeURIComponent($("#txtName").val()) + "&technology=" + encodeURIComponent($("#ddlTechnolgy").val());
            window.location.href = url;
        });
    });
</script>

<input type="button" id="btnQueryString" value="Send" />
```

Hope this will help u..

Answer (score 1):

I think I'd rather do something like

```
window.location.href= 'editviewposition.aspx?id=' + hidposid.value;
```

Or is there a reason this is not possible?

Comment: this is what i have tried before but its not working

Comment: are your sure there is a value in hidposid.value ?

Comment: The first line of code you show will add the id pramaeter to the current url and load that. So the current page will be loaded with that parameter. Thesecond line of code you show, will load the page "editviewposition.aspx" without any parameters. Actually you redirect twice, once to the current url with a parameter, once to the editviewposition.aspx without a parameter

Comment: what about the above u have given? will it pass the querystring

Comment: It'm quiet confident it should work that way. What is the url in your browser before HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString("id") is hit?

Comment: technically there's no difference than the accepted solution. Probably the problem was somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

Here you are passing query string not cookies
Get it like

```
window.location.search = '?id='+hidposid.value;
window.location.href="editviewposition.aspx";
```

and then in code behind

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString("id")
```

Comment: Should be brackets IIRC. Also, you can point to the querystring explicitly: `HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["id"]`

Comment: Sorry i write it in VB

Comment: sorry, i have modified the question. still having problem

Comment: PLease add ? to search